# What does getContentPane() do exactly?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

When to use:

```
Container c = getContentPane();
```

And when to use:

```
frame.getContentPane();
```

Comment: Huh? Can you give an example of each? What did the API tell you?

Comment: my textbook program uses only frame.getcontentpane .. but while actually implementing it it doesnt work. I have to use con = getcontentpane().. would u tell me mechanism of getcontentpane.. it may clear my all doubts.

Comment: Can you post some of your code? Does the class you are calling getContentPane() from in the first example extend JFrame?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the code is part of a `JFrame` subclass, you should use `getContentPane()`. If the code is not part of the frame (perhaps you're in the `static main()` method for the application), then you need to use a `JFrame` object to call `getContentPane()`; that's what `frame.getContentPane()` does.

Examples:

```
public class TestApp extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestApp frame = new TestApp();
        Container c = frame.getContentPane();
        // do something with c
        frame.pack();
        frame.show();
    }

    /* constructor */
    public TestApp() {
        Container c = getContentPane(); // same as this.getContentPane()
        // initialize contents of frame
    }
}
```

Comment: this frame i am talking about is not var of user class.. its of JFrame class

Comment: @ChinmayKale - Yeah, I should have realized that. `getContentPane()` is a Swing method. I think you got the basic idea, though.

Comment: So we can make same gui's with Only Container class or Only Jframe class? it doesnt matter?

Comment: @ChinmayKale - It matters. A `JFrame` is a particular type of `Container` that is intended to be shown as a top-level container for an app. A generic `Container` is pretty much any kind of visual component of a Java program that can hold other visual components. A `JFrame` itself contains a special `Container` called the _content pane_ in which most of its contained components are placed. (A `JFrame` also has a menu bar; other Swing container types may also have their own specialized components.) When you add components to a `JFrame`, they actually get added to its content pane.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 17):

```
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
```

---

This line of code is difficult to understand, and the tutor will lay the foundation for you to understand it fully as you continue to study Java.
First to consider is the rule about modifying an **object** with a **method**. On the left side of a **period** is an **object**, and the **method** that modifies the **object** is on the right side of the **period. That rule applies here.**

A **container** has several layers in it. You can think of a layer as a transparent film that overlays the **container**. In Java Swing, the layer that is used to hold objects is called the **content pane**. Objects are added to the content pane layer of the container. The `getContentPane()` method retrieves the content pane layer so that you can add an object to it. The content pane is an object created by the Java run time environment. You do not have to know the name of the content pane to use it. When you use `getContentPane()`, the content pane object then is substituted there so that you can apply a method to it. In this line of code, we are not adding an object to the content pane. Rather, we are making the color of the content pane to be yellow. This line of code is what changes the default color, white, to yellow, and you may recall seeing the yellow rectangle in the example the program running in a browser. This line of code is what made that rectangular area yellow.

One way to think about this is to think that the content pane object is substituted for the **getContentPane() method**, like this:

```
contentpaneobject.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
```

Although you never really see the above **statement**, you do have the functionality of the **statement**. When you retrieve the **content pane** with the `getContentPane()` **method**, you can then modify the **content pane object**, which is arbitrarily named contentpaneobject in the example above. In this statement, the modification is to change the color of the content pane. That step is presented next in the tutor.

Notice the form of `getContentPane()` as a **method**. The method begins with a lower case letter, and it has parentheses. The parentheses are empty.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well, I [could direct to the api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) :

> Returns the contentPane object for this frame.

[It's all part of the gui initialization process](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/cit591-2004/Pages/layout-examples.html). Java's protocol really, admittedly some boilerplate to get your GUI up:

```
public class FlowLayoutExample extends JApplet {

  public void init () {
    getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout ());
    getContentPane().add(new JButton("One"));
    getContentPane().add(new JButton("Two"));
    getContentPane().add(new JButton("Three"));
    getContentPane().add(new JButton("Four"));
    getContentPane().add(new JButton("Five"));
    getContentPane().add(new JButton("Six"));
  }
}
```

[-Source](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/cit591-2004/Pages/layout-examples.html)

But essentially, we're obtaining the content pane layer so that you can later add an object to it. [See this for more details.](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fuserpages.umbc.edu%2F~emurian%2FlearnJava%2Fswing%2Ftutor%2Fv2%2Fexplanations%2FExplain28.html&ei=jQoXVPapH46dygT0sIDABA&usg=AFQjCNECerqFXOGDtSwtW96rlyCgXZqwbQ&sig2=AGJeyKEI1A4G_yY7zzs5NQ&bvm=bv.75097201,d.aWw)

Answer (score 1):

Likely you are extending [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#getContentPane--) which means that the class will inherit the methods from `JFrame`. As such, your code may look somewhat like the following:

```
public class MyClass extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new MyClass();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public MyClass() {
        ...
        Container c = getContentPane();
    }
}
```

In the above example, there is no need to use `frame.getContentPane()` because you are inheriting the methods of `JFrame`. In other words, you only need to write `getContentPane()`. Alternatively, in most cases you should actually be **instantiating** a new `JFrame` as an instance variable unless you are actually adding new functionality to the `JFrame` class:

```
public class MyClass {
    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new MyClass();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public MyClass() {
        ...
        Container c = frame.getContentPane();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you we extend `JFrame` then we can use `getContentPane()` method direct in our `BoxLayout` object .
But if we apply association rule (means we create an Object of `JFrame` in our code i.e. `JFrame f=new JFrame()`), then we need to create  a Container object and pass this object in `BoxLayout()` as an argument.

1. When we extends JFrame:

   ```
   public class BoxLayOutTest extends JFrame {
       public BoxLayOutTest() {
           // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
           setSize(300, 400);
           setVisible(true);
           getContentPane().setLayout(new  BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
           JButton b1 = new JButton("One");
           JButton b2 = new JButton("Two");
           JButton b3 = new JButton("Three");
           JButton b4 = new JButton("Four");
           JButton b5 = new JButton("Five");

           add(b1);
           add(b2);
           add(b3);
           add(b4);
           add(b5);
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           new BoxLayOutTest();
       }
   }
   ```
2. If we create `JFrame` Object inside code:

   ```
   public class TwoPanelinFrame {
       JFrame f;

       public TwoPanelinFrame() {
           f = new JFrame("Panel Test");
           f.setSize(600, 600);
           f.setVisible(true);
           Container c = f.getContentPane();
           f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(c, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

           JButton b2 = new JButton("One");
           JButton b3 = new JButton("One");
           JButton b4 = new JButton("One");
           JButton b5 = new JButton("One");

           f.add(b2);
           f.add(b3);
           f.add(b4);
           f.add(b4);
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           new TwoPanelinFrame();
       }
   }
   ```